# Loop a query which use multiple Databases using a cursor

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to loop a query through multiple databases that I have listed in a table, I've tried to use a cursor and switch out the USE statement with the new database name but I keep getting an Incorrect syntax near '@DBName'. Is there any way to do this? Below is my attempt.

```
DECLARE  @DBName  varchar (100)
DECLARE  @Sql  varchar (100)
DECLARE  @Table   varchar (100) 
DECLARE  @IndexName varchar (100)
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
select DBName,[Table],IndexName from IndexOverview_FragLevels
OPEN TableCursor            
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @DBName, @Table, @IndexName                                                                                            
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
use @DBName;
DBCC DBREINDEX (@Table ,@IndexName, 90);
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @DBName,@Table,@IndexName
END
close TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

In this code I am reindexing the tables from multiple databases.In which  data is stores in a tables called IndexOverview_FragLevels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to execute the command in a dynamic SQL batch to set the database context. Below is a parameterized query example:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N';
    DBCC DBREINDEX (@Table, @IndexName, 90);';
EXECUTE sp_executesql
     @SQL
    ,N'@Table sysname, @IndexName sysname'
    ,@Table = @Table
    ,@IndexName = @IndexName;
```

Rather than reinvent the wheel, consider using [Ola Hallengren's T-SQL maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/), which is widely used and highly regarded in the SQL Server community.